# Size classes on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I'm using size classes for my app, but i met a problem with devices on iOS 7.

For example, I've an iPhone 4s under iOS 7.1 , and an iPhone 4s under iOS 8.

On my size classes, I did something for the landscape mode.

When I launch the app on the iPhone 4s (iOS 7.1), the landscape mode fail, it doesn't show the correct view, whereas the iPhone 4S (iOS 8) is showing the correct view that I set on the storyboard...

Someone has an idea ?

Thx,

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I found the problem... Apple's Doc :

"or apps supporting versions of iOS earlier than iOS 8, most size classes are backward compatible.

Size classes are backward compatible when:

The value of the height component is not compact"

Omg :(